# Utilizar Skip() LinQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo un método que debe de mostrar 10 nombres de una lista que le paso por parámetros, y cada vez que el usuario pulse una tecla se deben de mostrar los 10 siguientes. Bien, he estado leyendo sobre `take()` y `skip()`, pero solo he logrado implementar el `take()`

```
    public static void Ejer13(List<Heroe> h)
    {
        var lista = h.Take(10);

        foreach(var x in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
        }
    }
```

¿Como se implementa el `skip()`? Para poder ir mostrando los siguientes 10 nombres en este caso.

**EDITO**

De una forma un poco "chapuza" he conseguido que el programa haga lo que tiene que hacer, aunque me gustaría mejorarlo pero no se como...

```
    public static void Ejer13(List<Heroe> h)
    {
        int pocision = 0;
        string tecla;
        var lista = h.Skip(pocision).Take(10);

        do
        {
            foreach (var x in lista)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Escribe: ");
            tecla = Console.ReadLine();

            pocision += 10;

           lista = h.Skip(pocision).Take(10);

        } while (tecla == "S"); 
    }
```

Por ejemplo que el bucle `do-while` se repita hasta que no queden mas elementos en la lista. E intentar reducir un poco el código utilizando alguna función de LinQ, si es posible.

¿Como se podría hacer?

Comment: Skip es lo contrario de Take, ya que te sirve para omitir los registros que le especificas como parametro, y a partir de ese devolver el resto

Comment: Con esto lo he entendido mejor, y bueno algo he sacado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que intentas implementar es una paginacion

[How To Implement Paging Using Skip And Take Operators In LINQ](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-paging-using-skip-and-take-operators-in-linq/)

```
public static void Ejer13(List<Heroe> h, int page)
{

    if(page < 1)
        throw new Exception("la pagina debe ser mayor o igual a uno");

    var lista = h.Skip((page - 1) * 10)Take(10);

    foreach(var x in lista)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
    }
}
```

alli puse el `page size` fijo en 10, pero podrias cambiarlo si necesitas